# Split a vector into parts separated by zeros and cumulatively sum the elements in each part

Tags: sql, finance

I want to split a vector into several parts separated by the numeric value 0. For each part, cumulatively calculate the sum of the elements encountered so far. Negative numbers do not participate in the calculation.

For example, with the input `[0,1,1,1,0,1,-1,1,1]`, I expect the result to be `[0,1,2,3,0,1,1,2,3]`.

How to implement this in DolphinDB?

Comment: at you in a database so the data is saved? there are these vectors in the form of a table?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DolphinDB built-in function `cumPositiveStreak(X)`. Treat the negative elements in X as NULL values.

Script:

```
a = 1 2 -1 0 1 2 3
cumPositiveStreak(iif(a<0,NULL,a))
```

Execution result:

```
1 3 3 0 1 3 6
```